# Apache Airflow tasks are stuck in a 'up_for_retry' state

Tags: airflow

I've been setting up an airflow cluster on our system and previously it has been working. I'm not sure what I may have done to change this.

I have a DAG which I want to run on a schedule. To make sure it's working I'd also like to trigger it manually. Neither of these seem to be working at the moment and no logs seem to be being written for the task instances. The only logs available are the airflow scheduler logs which generally look healthy.

I am just constantly met with this message:

`Task is not ready for retry yet but will be retried automatically. Current date is 2018-12-12T11:34:46.978355+00:00 and task will be retried at 2018-12-12T11:35:08.093313+00:00.`

However, if I wait a little the exact same message is presented again except the times have moved forward a little. Therefore, it seems the task is never actually being retried.

I am using a LocalExecutor and the task is an SSHOperator. Simplified code below. All it does is ssh onto another machine and start a bunch of application with a pre-determined directory structure.:

```
DB_INFO_FILE = 'info.json'
START_SCRIPT = '/bin/start.sh'
TIME_IN_PAST = timezone.convert_to_utc(datetime.today() - 
timedelta(days=1))

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': TIME_IN_PAST,
    'email': ['some_email@blah.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

def _extract_instance_id(instance_string):
    return re.findall(r'\d+', instance_string)[0]

def _read_file_as_json(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as open_file:
         return json.load(open_file)

DB_INFO = _read_file_as_json(DB_INFO_FILE)
CONFIG_CLIENT = ConfigDbClient(**DB_INFO)

APP_DIRS = CONFIG_CLIENT.get_values('%my-app-info%')

INSTANCE_START_SCRIPT_PATHS = {
    _extract_instance_id(instance_string): directory+START_SCRIPT
    for instance_string, directory in APP_DIRS.items()
    }

# Create an ssh hook which refers to pre-existing connection information
# setup and stored by airflow
SSH_HOOK = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='my-conn-id')

# Create a DAG object to add tasks to
DAG = DAG('my-dag-id',
          default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS)

# Create a task for each app instance.
for instance_id, start_script in INSTANCE_START_SCRIPT_PATHS.items():
    task = SSHOperator(
        task_id='run-script-{0}'.format(instance_id),
        command='bash {0}'.format(start_script),
        ssh_hook=SSH_HOOK,
        dag=DAG)
```

It works when I run the tasks individually, via the command line but not via the UI. It seems I can run tasks but I simply cannot trigger a DAG to run. I've tried many combinations of start_date s and interval schedules just to sanity check also.

Any ideas?

And yes, I am aware this question has been asked before and I have looked at all of them but not of the solutions have helped me.

Comment: I seem to have found the reason. It seems to work when I run `airflow scheduler`, including the built in daemon `airflow scheduler -D`. However, when I run the daemon that I have setup using the unit files recommend by airflow the tasks either fail or get caught in an 'up_for_retry' state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh. Your `start_date` is changing at the same rate or faster than the schedule interval period.

Here's what the scheduler is seeing every couple of seconds:

```
start_date: 2018-12-11T12:12:12.000Z  # E.G. IFF now is 2018-12-12T12:12:12.000Z, a day ago
schedule_interval: timedelta(days=1)  # The default
```

Here's what the scheduler needs for a DAG to run: The last time a run occurred was more than one schedule interval ago. If no **scheduled** run has occurred, the first **scheduled** run could start now if one full schedule interval has passed since the `start_date` as that is the earliest allowable date for `execution_date`. In which case the `dag_run` with the `execution_date` set to the start of that interval period should be created. Then `task_instance`s can be created for any tasks in the DAG whose dependencies are met as long as the `task_instance` `execution_date` is after the `start_date` of the DAG (this is not stored on the `dag_run` object but recomputed by loading the DAG file just while inspecting the dag's state).

So it's not getting scheduled automatically for the reason that the start date keeps changing just as the interval is satisfied. However if it were -2d at least one run would get scheduled and then any further runs would have to wait until it's 1d after that to be scheduled. It's easier though if you just set a fixed `datetime` on your `start_date`.

But what about those odd retries on your manual runs…

You did start a manual run or two. These runs took the current time as the `execution_date` unless you specified something else. This should be after the `start_date`, at least until tomorrow, which should clear them to run. But then it seems in your logs you're seeing that they're failing and being marked for retry and also not decrementing your retries. I'm not sure why that would be but could it be that something isn't right with the `SSHOperator`.

Did you install airflow with the `[ssh]` extra so that SSHOperator's dependencies are met (specifically `paramiko` and `sshtunnel`) on both the webserver and scheduler? One of them is working because I assume it's parsing and showing up in the UI based on being added to the DB.

What do you get if you execute:

```
airflow test my-dag-id run-script-an_instance_id 2018-12-12T12:12:12
```

You know that the scheduler and webserver are looping over refilling their DAG bag and so rerunning this DAG file a few 1000 times a day, reloading that json (it's local access, so similar to importing a module), and recreating that `SSHHook` with a DB lookup. I don't see anything fancy done setting up this hook, why not just remove `ssh_hook` from the `SSHOperator` and replace it with `ssh_conn_id='my-conn-id'` so it can be created once at execution time?
I doubt that's the issue that's causing the retries that just roll forward though.

Answer (score 2):

I had a task stuck in `up_for_retry` for almost 24 hours before I noticed it, and it had nothing to do with the start_date, end_date, or any other classic beginner's problem.

I resorted to reading the source code, and found that Airflow treats `up_for_retry` tasks differently if they are part of a backfill DAG run.

So I connected to the metadata DB and changed `backfill_` to `scheduled__` in the `dag_run` row corresponding to the stuck task. Airflow started running the stuck task immediately.