# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor Gets in an Infinite UP_FOR_RETRY Loop After the First Timeout

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

*Alert: I'm aware this question has been asked a couple times, though slightly differently and none of the provided possible solutions resolved my case, so that's why I'm asking here.*

**Context:**

I'm running a few DAGs in a row:

`A --> B --> C`

Where A, B, and C are different DAGs. B will run once A has finished, and C will run once B has finished. They are daily DAGs, start at the same time, and have retry_exponential_backoff off. The DAGs are created with the default parameters, with the exception of `retry_delay` which I override to 1 second. Example below:

```
DAG(
    "dag_A",
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    default_args=dict(
        start_date=datetime(2019, 10, 8, 22),
        retries=4,
        retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=1),
        ...
    ),
)
```

In order to kickoff B, and C, I have an `ExternalTaskSensor` waiting on the previous DAG to finish

```
sensor_in_B = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id="sensor_in_B",
    external_dag_id="dag_A",
    external_task_id="task_in_A",
    poke_interval=30,
    timeout=240,
)
```

**The problem:**

Taking `B` as an example (but it also happens with C). `B`'s sensor has a timeout of 240 seconds. But `A` takes more than 240 seconds to finish. So, currently, `B` will always timeout at least once, until A finishes. The problem happens after the first timeout. B's sensor task get stuck in a `UP_FOR_RETRY` state and cannot leave that except for manual intervention through the Airflow UI. Here is the error observed:

```
Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: dag_B.sensor_in_B 2019-12-08 15:00:00 [up_for_retry]>, dependency 'Not In Retry Period' FAILED: Task is not ready for retry yet but will be retried automatically. Current date is 2019-12-09T15:08:39.861820 and task will be retried at 2019-12-09T15:08:40.007209.
```

Sometimes it happens after the first timeout. Sometimes it only happens after the second timeout. But it always run the first try with no errors. Also, sometimes the error doesn't happen and execution runs fine. The error above, when it happens, appears not only once, but once every 10 seconds, and require manual intervention to stop. The difference between the current time and retry time is always tiny, in the millisecond range (around ~0.1 seconds).

**One guess...**

I had a feeling that this could be related to the very low `retry_period` of 1 second I use.

The error message seems to be originated [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/ti_deps/deps/not_in_retry_period_dep.py#L46-L48), and you can see that the `cur_date` and `next_task_retry_date`, which are the values that get rendered in the error message are calculated *before* the actual comparison, which happens following the path of that `is_premature()` call. My guess is that it takes more than those ~0.1 seconds to actually get to [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a36cfe049a2c5948b24fde7a878fe19cabede5f7/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L684) which is the place the decision to fail is made, and then it gets [re-scheduled](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a36cfe049a2c5948b24fde7a878fe19cabede5f7/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1043-L1094) and this error loop continues.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744198/apache-airflow-tasks-are-stuck-in-a-up-for-retry-state) similar question though had the same problem and used a 1 minute retry_delay, so it may *not* be because of the 1 second retry_period that I used.